# VBA Actively Deleting Users from a Collection on a Loop Referencing same Collection.Count

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a sheet that lists users of a program. Users may be listed multiple times, so I made a program to filter user's data and email it to them. To accomplish this I used the **collection** method to list users and email information.

I am writing a subsection of code that will delete users who have no entries in my sheet. Essentially, if their username doesn't exist, delete them from the collection.

I'm fairly certain the problem is in my For loop from n=1 to MyPeople.Count, because i'm actively removing entries from MyPeople. There are 34 to start, and it errors out when at 29 (after removing 6 total). The problem is that I don't know how to fix this.

```
You can see my attempts in the If cel.Value=0 section
```

Code:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyUsers()
Dim RemoveDecider As Integer
RemoveDecide = 0
Dim test As Integer
test = 0
Set rng = Range("B17", Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1))
    For n = 1 To MyPeople.Count
        For Each cel In rng
            If cel.Value = MyPeople(n).SiView Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If cel.Value = 0 Then 'the last empty cell after all entries are checked for user
                MsgBox (MyPeople(n).FirstName & " has been removed")
                MyPeople.Remove (n)
                n = n - 1
                MyPeople.Count
                test = test + 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: When doing loops like this, it is best to start from the highest value and go to 1.  When you delete a row, your indices get messed up.

Comment: Always remove starting from the end and moving backward.

Comment: Good point. I'll try that and get back to this question if I do solve the answer myself.

Comment: I'm attempting to count backwards, but this is where i'm confused in using mypeople.count

Comment: For MyPeople.Count to n = 1 Step -1

Comment: This prompts for an "=" somewhere as it thinks one is missing.

Comment: `For n = MyPeople.Count to 1 Step -1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop should be something like this:

```
n = MyPeople.Count
While n > 0
    [do code]
    n = n - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Shouldn't it just be `For n = MyPeople.Count To 1 Step -1`?

Comment: Ah, I prefer while loops, I am sorry. Editing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. The above comments were true. I needed to reverse the loop. As you can see, now I count from n=mypeople.count to 1. After doing so:

```
Sub RemoveEmptyUsers()
Dim RemoveDecider As Integer
RemoveDecide = 0
Dim test As Integer
test = 0
Set rng = Range("B17", Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1))
MsgBox (MyPeople.Count)
    For n = MyPeople.Count To 1 Step -1
        For Each cel In rng
            If cel.Value = MyPeople(n).SiView Then
                Exit For
            End If
            If cel.Value = 0 Then 'the last empty cell after all entries are checked for user
                MsgBox (MyPeople(n).FirstName & " has been removed")
                MyPeople.Remove (n)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cel
    Next n
End Sub
```